# Dont print value select from database with inner join of 2 tables using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I cant get the value selected from database using yii framework with inner join.My controller is sitecontroller.php and view file is adavance_search_result.php.I got the error "

Property "Job.ltitle" is not defined.

```
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(145)".
```

**jobs table fields**

```
id int (100)
user_id int(100)
posted_by varchar(100)
title varchar(100)
key_skills varchar(200)
no_vacancy int(11)
category_id int(11)
experience int(11)
contact_email varchar(100)
company_name varchar(100)
salary double
location_id int int(100)
```

**location table**

```
1.id

2.title
```

**My controller join query is**

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 't.title,  location.title as ltitle,  t.id,  t.key_skills,      t.description, t.no_vacancy, t.experience, t.company_name, t.salary';
$criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN location ON t.location_id = location.id';
if($title!="")
{

  $criteria->addCondition("t.title like '%$title%' or  t.key_skills like '%$title%'");  
}
if($experience!="")
{

  $criteria->addCondition("experience like '%$experience%'");    
}
if($location!="")
{
   $criteria->addCondition("location_id like '%$location%'");
}

if($category!="")
{
   $criteria->addCondition("category_id like '%$category%'");
}
if($salary_min!="" && $salary_max!="")
    {
        $criteria->addCondition("salary >= '$salary_min' and salary <=   '$salary_max'");
    }
```

My view file code

```
 <p><?php echo $models->tile    ; ?></p>
<p><?php echo CHtml::link($models['title'] ); ?></p>
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try use Yii relations:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query

then your JOIN-s will be easier.